# Indenting only some sections in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents

I want to indent some sections in the TOC but leave the fact that they're unnumbered and not indented in the body unchanged.  Example follows.

In the example below I would want "Test" in the TOC to be aligned with "1.1 Section Foo" so that the "T" is right under the "S", while leaving the formatting of the body unchanged and still no numbering of "Test" in the TOC.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{bookman}
\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{standard}
\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{#1~}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\newenvironment{test}[1]{%
  \subsection*{#1}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter Foo}
\section{Section Foo}
\subsection{Subsection Foo}
\begin{test}{Test}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Test}
\subsubsection*{Subsection Foo Star}
\end{test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In fact it's aligned. If you think it's not you can just try with `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{ Test}` i.e.  with additional space in `{ Test}`.

Comment: You are right.  I apologize.  I meant aligning the "T" with the "S".  I'm editing my question.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Here are the changes to make to my original example:

1. Change tocdepth argument from 1 to 2 to show subsections.
2. Change subsections I do want in the TOC from \subsection to \subsection*.
3. Change the addcontentsline argument from section to subsection.